# Wand Outputs Too Many Images

Tags: python, wand

So I'm relatively inexperienced with python in general, and brand new to ImageMagick and Wand, however, the tools are doing 95% of what I need so far which means a LOT of time saved in the long term for a project I'm working on.

I am simply taking a folder of images, converting them from .tiff to .png, then saving them to a subfolder. Seems simple, right? And the code below is working:

```
# Import os functions for setting path and getting files from directory
import os

# Import Wand functions to get the image and the required colors to convert
from wand.image import Image
from wand.color import Color

# Set the path where the images are being held
sourcePath = '/somePath/'
destinationPath = '/somePath/batch/'

# Set the image extenion we want to process and convert to
sourceExt = 'tiff'
destinationExt = 'png'

# Use os to get all files held in that directory
files = os.listdir(sourcePath)

# Loop through every file
for file in files:

    # Get the current image file's name and extension
    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(sourcePath + file)
    print('Filename: ' + filename)
    print('File extension: ' + file_extension)

    updatedFilename = filename.replace(sourcePath, '')

    # Only process for images with the .tiff extension
    if file_extension == ('.' + sourceExt):

        with Image(filename=filename + file_extension) as img:
            img.format = 'png'
            with Color('#FFFFFF') as white:
                img.transparent_color(white, alpha=0.0)
            img.save(filename=destinationPath + updatedFilename + '.' + destinationExt)
```

In general, the code is working well, outputting .png versions of my input files with the white background stripped out.

However, I am taking in 80 images and the output is a total of 712 images. Is there something with Wand specifically that is causing this, or is it my loop in python?

Comment: You have the `print(Filename)` statements in the loop. What does that output? 80 file names, or 712 file names?

Comment: Your code *ought* to be working. The only possibility I see is that some or all of those TIFF files are actually *multi-image* TIFFs. In that case you might need to seek() the desired sub-image and save that.

You should be able to see whether this is the case from the file names themselves.

Comment: You may have multipage TIFFs. To fix that, just select the first page by appending [0] to the end of the file suffix. Try `with Image(filename=filename + file_extension + "[0]") as img:`

Comment: As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Might be worth posting your findings as an answer, and accept it. This will help future readers with similar issues know it was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My .tiff files were secretly multi-page files, and I was getting all of the pages rather than just the first. I've resolved this issue accidentally by exporting my images in a better supported .png format (with the added benefit of my dumped images not having a background to be stripped out anymore) but this was very helpful.